# Automatic chart generation in DC.js

Tags: javascript, html, dc.js

I want to know if it's possible to generate chart in an automatic way (with a generic function).

For example in my html I specify type of chart (pie chart, row chart,..) then it's added in my web page automatically (may be with DOM)?

Comment: There have been a few attempts to build libraries on top of dc.js that will construct whole dashboards, but I don't know if any of these have been completed. So yes, it's possible, but I don't know of any general and easy way.

Comment: Another route could be to use [angular-dc](https://github.com/TomNeyland/angular-dc) to generate your dashboard using templates.